# Display 2 cursors at the same time using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cursor, position, mouse, chat

I'm actually working on a video conferencing project and I was wondering if there is any way to display 2 cursors at the same time based on mouses' position of the 2 guys talking to each other?

Basically, they gonna share the same screen, but I want one to be able to see the mouse pointer of the other one since they gonna work on common exercice.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easiest to have a div element with a custom mouse cursor that you move around in JavaScript by the coordinates received from the other user?

I think having two equal-looking cursors would just cause confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification. It's indeed a good solution :)